# What time of each blind level in home game should be?

Tags: blinds, home-game, sng

I'm a poker newbie, please tell me how to set up a blind structure in the home game?
What time for each blind level should be and what is the optimal time for one session should be?

Are 10 minutes for a blind level turbo set up?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blind period suggestions](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/11592/blind-period-suggestions)

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: a simple way is to double blinds on each tournament round